# How to close two activities in one button click?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

There are 3 activities A, B, C.

A has `onCreate` with many animations (only for the start up) and `onRestart` with one animation (every time on restart).

B has `onClick` button to C.

C has "Go to A" button. (Button click -> Activity C -> Activity A)

I made it like this:

```
public void gotoA (View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and it creates again, and the start up animations show up.

How do I close (or kill) two activities at once?

Also I tried `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` for this, but it didn't work.

Comment: There is only 1 Activity running at a time, so this may confuse people (maybe you can restate your ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

startActivityForResult from Activity A->B and B->C, then set result_code to something specific in C. Then in onActivityResult in B check for that result_code and call finish.

You should try to avoid FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, as it does not finish your activity properly, simply removes it from view.

Comment: Are there no way to finish two activities (B, C) at once to show A?

Comment: No, you can only use workarounds, but they won't finish the Activities cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what do you want here with tying to kill two activities, and you dont have any code posted , so i can only tell you to try with adding

```
 finish();
```

after

```
 startActivity(intent);
```

that should close yours activity

Comment: I mean there are start up animations in Activity A, and when I use startActivity(intent); it creates Activity A, and it shows start up animation again.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to finish the first two Activities when you start your third Activity. For achieving this you can use the following setup:

- When starting the second Activity from the first Activity, use startActivityForResult
- When starting the third Activity from the second one, set a result code that you have chosen to send to the first Activity to signal it to finish itself
- Now finish the second Activity
- Now you will receive the termination result code from the second Activity in the `onActivityResult()` method of the first Activity. Call finish() here to finish the first Activity as well